# Virtualbox - Headless start - connect via VBoxmanager

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012-r2

I am running a VBox-VM in headless mode via automatic task on WinSRV 2012r2.

I use the following code: `VBoxManage.exe startvm Router --type headless`

Is it possible to connect to the VM via Virtual Box Manager, while it is running?

When I start VBox Manager, the VM is listed as 'not running'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a VM via Virtual Box Manager's Buttons it's intern the same command with the option `--type gui`.

So when you run the machine headless with your command:

```
VBoxManage.exe startvm Router --type headless
```

And subsequently with `gui` option

```
VBoxManage.exe startvm Router --type gui
```

You will notice that it isn't possible and that there will pop up an error message (here with Powershell example):

```
PS C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> .\VBoxManage.exe startvm     Router  --type headless
VBoxManage.exe: error: The machine 'Router' is already locked by a session (or being locked or unlocked)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "LaunchVMProcess(a->session, sessionType.raw(), env.raw(), progress.asOutParam())" at li
ne 589 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

So the answer on your question

> Is it possible to connect to the VM via Virtual Box Manager, while it is running?

is no.

But if you reproduce this and receive another error message there is something else wrong.